# subquery: is it good practise to use having clause to filter out rows of outer query that contains subquery's null values

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, filtering, having-clause

I have the following tables:

`SELECT * FROM medicine`

```
| id | name        | producer |
+----+-------------+----------+
|  1 | aspirin     | pharma   |
|  2 | cetamol     | tamiko   |
|  3 | brufen      | pharma   |
|  4 | cetacodeine | adamco   |
|  5 | actifed     | tamiko   |
|  6 | claritin    | tamiko   |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

`SELECT * FROM liquid`

```
+-----+------+-------+
| lid | m_id | price |
+-----+------+-------+
| l1  |    2 |  1000 |
| l2  |    3 |  1500 |
| l3  |    4 |  3000 |
| l4  |    5 |  2000 |
| l5  |    6 |  1800 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

`SELECT * FROM tablet`

```
+-----+------+-------+
| tid | m_id | price |
+-----+------+-------+
| t1  |    1 |   900 |
| t2  |    2 |   600 |
| t3  |    3 |  1200 |
| t4  |    5 |  2000 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

Where **m_id** in the last two tablest has foriegn key referencing to **id** in the first table.

I'm trying to list **lid** and **name** of medicines that are liquid and produced only by producer *tamiko*
Executing the following statement will result in rows that contains null values returned from the subquery and I want to omit

`SELECT lid, (SELECT name FROM medicine WHERE liquid.m_id=medicine.id AND medicine.producer='tamiko') AS byTamiko FROM liquid;`

```
+-----+----------+
| lid | byTamiko |
+-----+----------+
| l1  | cetamol  |                                                                                 
| l2  | NULL     |                                                                                 
| l3  | NULL     |                                                                                  
| l4  | actifed  |                                                                                 
| l5  | claritin |                                                                                
+-----+----------+
```

So I had some tries and using `HAVING` clause seems like a solution

`SELECT lid, (SELECT name FROM medicine WHERE liquid.m_id=medicine.id AND medicine.producer='tamiko') AS byTamiko FROM liquid HAVING byTamiko IS NOT NULL;`

```
| lid | byTamiko |
+-----+----------+
| l1  | cetamol  |
| l4  | actifed  |
| l5  | claritin |
+-----+----------+
```

However, my teacher disagreed saying that `HAVING` clause should be only used with aggregated functions and along with `GROUP BY` statement. I'm now confused whether this is an appropriate usage or not? and what happened exactly that made it work?

Note: I have to do this query using sub queries only and not any `JOIN` or different statement.

Note2: Be aware that This is not a duplicated, I'm trying to get an explanation on how it worked and whether it's an correct usage or not.

Comment: Actually, your subquery should be replaced with `JOIN` to run once and not for every row of outer table. If you are running subquery for learning exercise, ignore this advisement

Comment: @Parfait yes I'm running it for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really appropriate.

In the SQL Standard `having` is defined as filtering *after* aggregation and `where` is for filtering before aggregation (if there is any aggregation).

MySQL extends this to allow `having` in non-aggregation queries.  This extension allows you to filter on column aliases without using a subquery.  But you should use `where` for filtering before aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

so it should look like this?

```sql
SELECT lid, (
    SELECT name 
    FROM medicine 
    WHERE liquid.m_id=medicine.id AND medicine.producer='tamiko'
) AS byTamiko 
FROM liquid 
WHERE byTamiko IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Did you try that? You can't filter an alias with ```WHERE``` clause